# Solving for $s$ in $E[(1-h)^s]$ in terms of moments of $h$

Tags: sequences-and-series, probability-theory, moment-generating-functions

Suppose $h$ is a discrete random variable with probability of seeing $h_i$ proportional to $h_i$, and moments $M_k=E[h^k]$ exist for $k=1,2,\ldots$. Is it possible to get bounds on $s$ where the following holds, in terms of $M_k$?

$$E[(1-h)^s]<\epsilon$$

**edit**
This problem comes up in average case analysis of gradient descent. $s$ gives the number of gradient descent steps needed to obtain average loss target $\epsilon$ when minimizing quadratic form with eigenvalues a multiple of $h_1,h_2,\ldots,$. Algorithms exist for computing $M_k$ in in practice, for small values of $k$, algorithm for $s$ is missing. A different approach which doesn't rely on $M_k$ but makes strong assumptions on form of $h$ is given [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/2006.04299)

Comment: Please provide additional context, which ideally explains why the question is relevant to you and our community. Some forms of context include: background and motivation, relevant definitions, source, possible strategies, your current progress, why the question is interesting or important, etc.

Comment: @JitendraSingh added motivation

Comment: $(1-h)^s$ is a polynomial in $h$ and its expectation is a sum of moments of $h$  I assume $s$ us an integer.

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov So you want to find the smallest $s$ (say $s_0$) such that $E[(1-h)^s]<\epsilon$? In other words, $E[(1-h)^{s_0}] = \epsilon$. And you want to bound $s_0$? Upper bound or lower bound or approximation?

Answer (score 0):

Partial way towards solution.

Use the following approximation:
$$(1-h)^s \approx exp(-h s)$$

Now, without loss of generality, assume $M_1=1$. Then $h_i$ add up to 1, and we can write expectation as

$$E[(1-h)^s]\approx \sum_{i} \exp[-h_i s] h_i$$

This is the moment generating function $g(s)$ of the following distribution:
$$p(-h_i)=h_i$$

Hence the problem comes down to finding smallest $s$ such that $g(s)<\epsilon$

The Taylor approximation of $g$ is written in terms of $M_1,M_2,\ldots$, now need to find how to bound the error of Taylor approximation if we drop terms beyond first $k$

**Edit**
Taylor approximation actually tends to give quite a poor fit to the solution. Example of plotting true mgf vs first 5 approximation orders:
[image]